# How to use Smarty variables inside of Smarty function calls?

Tags: php, smarty

I want to show some value on my site.
The value is declare as:

```
    {$statistics.cashout}
```

how I can get the value of it, and past it into this:

```
    {fetch file='https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=$statistics.cashout' assign='btc'}
```

like this I have try it and do not works...

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Bono Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message '{fetch} cannot read resource 'https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=$statistics.cashout''

Comment: @Jerome "How to do that in Smarty?" Kindly, try to explain your issue in the title, not `I want to a thing in whatever`

Comment: @SaifHamed Sorry, I was not knowing in this moment, how to explain it in one title.

Comment: @Jerome: Suggested title: "How do I concatenate strings in Smarty?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the concatenation filter (or are they called something else in smarty? its been awhile):

```
{fetch file='https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value='|cat:$statistics.cashout assign='btc'}
```